# Unhandled Promise rejection: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. Using SwitchMap and a function of type Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, recaptcha, rxjs-observables

this is my first time using `switchMap` from the rxjs library.

Im guessing this error message means its unhappy with how I am doing things.

Observe my `addemail` function

```
addemail(form:NgForm){
    this.googlerecaptchaservice.verifyinteraction('general_marketing_email_signup')
      .subscribe(
        (score: any)=>{
          console.log(score);
          const value = form.value.emailaddform;
          this.addemailservice.add_email_to_general_marketing(value)
            .subscribe(
              (req: any)=>{
                console.log('here is the test');
                console.log(req);
              }
            );
        });

  }
```

more specifically the `googlerecaptchaservice.verifyinteraction`

```
verifyinteraction(action): Observable<any>{
    return this.recaptchaV3Service.execute(action).pipe(
      switchMap((value: any) => {
        const payload = {
        token: value
        };
        this.http.post(
          'http://127.0.0.1:8000/verify/recaptcha', payload
        );

      }));
  }
```

what I don't understand is why am I getting the error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SwitchMap` should return an Observable, modify you code as following

```js
verifyinteraction(action): Observable<any>{
    return this.recaptchaV3Service.execute(action).pipe(
      switchMap((value: any) => {
        const payload = {
        token: value
        };
        return this.http.post(
          'http://127.0.0.1:8000/verify/recaptcha', payload
        );

      }));
  }
```

Comment: oh ok so I still have to return the observable when using operators like `swtichMap` thank you. I will accept your answer when it allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

SwitchMap expects an Observable so you need to return this.http.post